# Gatsby develop command is not working showing TypeError: is.urlInstance is not a function

Tags: npm, gatsby

TypeError: is.urlInstance is not a function

There's also dependency errors I tried to update gatsby version but not working

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-hello-world@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@3.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^3.1.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^2.13.12" from gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images@0.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images
npm ERR!   gatsby-wpgraphql-inline-images@"^0.2.5" from the root project

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you have a plugin that is not well installed or written in the gatsby-config.js file.

You can try to make the plugin script as a comment in your file (mine was the gatsby-source-medium script, I commented the section):

```
modules.exports = { plugins: [ /*{ resolve : 'gatsby-source-medium', options: { username: `@kennstack`}}*/ ] }
```

For my case, the problem was with the gatsby-source-medium plugin.

After fixing that, then you can go to the docs and try to install the plugin efficiently.

Let me know how you've solved it!